# How to set a default password

Tags: php, html, laravel, password-protection

I have a question ... I have a system developed in laravel 8, and I would like to know how to set it a default password, I have it this way but I don't know if it's okay:

CONTROLLER (from my controller I send the password)

```
   public function index()
    {
        $contra='hola123';
        return  view('administrador.users.create',compact('contra'));
    }
```

VIEW

```
  <div class="mt-4" align="center">
       <x-jet-label for="password" value="{{ __('Password: ') }}" />
       <x-jet-input id="password" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="password" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password" value="{{$contra}}" />
   </div>
```

The downside is that by selecting "Inspect" in Google Chrome, anyone can change the default password.

Comment: Do you want them to have a password they *cannot* change, or just a default if they don't want to set their own?

Comment: Is admin setting a password and you are suggesting one on your own? If true, the inspect element thing is no where an issue.

Comment: If you don't want your users to make a modification to the password then you can set it after they submit the form. Do let us know what you really want in the question. Thanks

Comment: What a fool I am ... it was just putting the password in the store of my controller. I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

A simply solution would be to just use the `Str::random()` helper and make the password fairly long to avoid problems with password randomness.

```
<x-jet-label for="password" value="{{ Str::random(24) }}" />
```

[Xkcd for reference](https://xkcd.com/936/)

Answer (score 0):

On `RegisterController` `validator` method you can make the password field nullable، then on the `create` method you can check if the password is null give the user a default password `bcrypt('mypassword')` otherwise save the password they entered `bcrypt(request()->password)`.

The previous method works on registration, but the same logic is applicable on other routes that required this feature

And hey, You really don't want to pass any password to a blade file.

Comment: I'm stupid ... it was just putting the password in the store of my controller. Thanks